# ValueError: <Too many values to unpack>

Tags: python, mongodb

Task is to find,sort,and remove the student with 'type': "homework" and with the lowest score using MongoDB. I also tried to use `toArray()` function,but it gave an error. Now I try to move on in document as a number of counter and to remove the last sorted document with the lowest score.

```
import pymongo 
import sys       

#establish a connection to the database
connection = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")

def delete_lowest_doc():

    #get a handle to the students database
    db=connection.students
    grades = db.grades


    try:
        for i in range(0,grades.find().count()):
            docs_1 = grades.find({'type':"homework", 'student_id':i}).sort(['score',-1])

            counter_1 = grades.find({'type':"homework",'student_id':i})
            counter_2 = counter_1.sort(['score',-1]).count() 

            while (counter_2>0):
                doc = docs_1.next();
                counter_2=counter_2-1;
            grades.remove(doc)


    except Exception as e:
        print ("Unexpected error:", type(e), e)

delete_lowest_doc()
```

Answer (score 1):

`collection.find` only takes one positional argument and you're giving it two.

Change your calls so that they look like the following: `grades.find({"type": "homework", "student_id": i})`.