# How can I fix error: Too many values to unpack : self.__ordering = helpers._index_document(keys)

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, ipython, pymongo

I get an error: Too many values to unpack. and then also:

self.__ordering = helpers._index_document(keys)

NOTE: I tried to make use of this link.

[Python ValueError: too many values to unpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053551/python-valueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack)

Code is as following:

```
docs = grades.find({'type':"homework",'student_id':i})
docs = docs.sort(['score',-1])
counter = grades.find({'type':"homework",'student_id':i})
counter = counter.sort(['score',-1]).count()
```

Comment: Show us the whole error message.

Comment: [And please don't repost!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356854/valueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
docs = docs.sort(['score',-1])
```

Should be this:

```
docs = docs.sort([('score',-1)])
```

Or this:

```
docs = docs.sort('score',-1)
```

[See the docs here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.8/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.sort).